# SDKDDKVer.h missing?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I just did an install of Visual Studio 2012 on a clean installation on Windows 7 and I cannot find `SDKDDKVer.h` anywhere on my disc. I have installed [Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279). However, the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\` folder does not contain any `include` folders.

What could I be missing?

Comment: I don't suppose you checked *before* you installed the Windows 7 SDK (and with it, the VC2010 compiler, etc.)? The 8.0 SDK ships with 2012, so is there something specific you need out of the 7.0/7.1 SDK?

Comment: Mine is in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared` if that helps (I think you need [Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/hh852363))

Comment: @WhozCraig: I did check before installing the SDK, the reason I installed the SDK was because the file was missing.

Comment: @JesseGood: It is not there, it is no where on disc, and I can't find any installation package that would add it...